# calculate row and column of data point

Tags: math, layout

I have a fixed number of columns that must be filled (if possible) with a data set. The requirement is that the data is filled top-bottom, left-right

so, for example, given that I have 4 columns, and 6 data points, the table must be filled like this

```
1 3 5 6
2 4
```

or for 3 columns and 7 data points

```
1 4 7
2 5 
3 6
```

I have tried multiple ways of calculating this, and if I were back in high school, would probably be able to solve it in a snap. But I am old and grey and my maths isn't as good as it was ;)

Would appreciate any pointers. Many thanks.

Comment: What are the requirements? E.g. why is the second example not `{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}` or `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6}, {7}`?

Comment: thanks for responding. the requirement is to a) ensure all columns are filled, and b) to be filled vertically then horizontally.  So for the second example, because 3 columns have to be filled, there needs to be three rows

Comment: Why must it be 3 rows then? The other two examples I presented also fill three columns (the numbers enclosed in `{ }` are supposed to be in the same column)?

Comment: because the client wants the data to be filled column by column, (ie column 1 has 1,2,3,4 .. n) but also wants all three columns to be filled (even if the last column just has 1 row)

Comment: So what is wrong with putting a single number in each column and every remaining number in the first column?

Comment: requirements. Client wants the grid filled as much as possible, top-to-bottom, left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "filled as much as possible" you mean that the percentage of filled cells is as large as possible. This problem has usually no unique solution but the following algorithm can be used to find *a* solution.

I further assume that `n` is the number of entries, `c` the number of columns, and `r` the number of rows.

```
r = ceil(n / c)
remainingAdditionalEntries = n - c
optimalAdditionalEntries = r - 1
nextEntry = 0
for iC from 0 to c - 1
    grid[iC][0] = nextEntry++
    additionalEntries = min(remainingAdditionalEntries, optimalAdditionalEntries)
    for iR from 1 to additionalEntries
        grid[iC][iR] = nextEntry++
    next
    remainingAdditionalEntries -= additionalEntries
next
```

The algorithm assumes that in each column there is at least one entry. The remaining cells may be filled by additional entries as long as they exist.